# relationship between the binary executables and the rest of the python installation

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have python version 3.4 installed on my computer. One part of the installation is the directory with the binary executables:

```
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/
```

As far as I understand it, these binary executables constitute the framework, which makes it possible for the computer to understand, e.g., what it means, if I type in the command

```
 import numpy
```

But I don't yet fully understand the the relationship between the binary executables and the rest of the python installation (e.g. the python modules and packages such as numpy). Why don't the files in the numpy package need to be executable binaries?

I would like to have an explanation of this from scratch/"for dummies".

Is there a good reference or can somebody write one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, `python` and `pip` are binary executables.

`numpy` is a module.

You cannot run a command called `numpy` from the terminal, therefore it is not a binary executable.

Some python packages are binary executables and you can execute them directly from the command line